# Swift Server Implementation

Tags: ios, swift, server

I am looking at trying to create an app the takes information provided from databases from stores and transfers this data to the app (into a spreadsheet or useable data form of some kind) and then be able to use this data within the app.
This data will also need to be able to be updated.
These are the thing I need to know

- How to access these servers and retrieve the data at will
- How to store this data for the app to use

If someone could please direct me to a series of tutorials about this sort of thing or provide some information that I can google and find out about that would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started. This is for network calls.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial. Storing data in app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to learn tutorials if you know all about HTTP and Swift well. Well, I can provide you some fast way that you can learn

> **For HTTP Services** :

REST Web Services => [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

SOAP Web Services => [Handling SOAP request using NSURLSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869943/handle-xml-parsed-response-in-swift/40879633#40879633)

If you use those, I am sure that you can do HTTP Request easily.

So, as soon as you get the response data from HTTP Request, you will have to parse it, `JSON or XML`.

> **For response parsing :**

JSON : [Swifty JSON : which can handle JSON more easy way](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

XML : [SWXMLHash : which can let you handle XML easy way](https://github.com/drmohundro/SWXMLHash/)

So, as soon as you can parse JSON or XML that you get from HTTP request, you need somewhere to store it right? You can use SQLite Database or Realm. So, you can store it and get it back anytime you need at your local devices application memory storage.

> **For storing and getting result data from database:**

Realm Swift : [Realm ORM Database : which is easy to learn and useful and quick](https://realm.io)

These are all the Info you need. Displaying the data is based on your design theory.

> **For further more reading :**

[Alamofire Beginner Guide : AppCoda](https://www.appcoda.com/alamofire-beginner-guide/)

[Parsing Data and Swifty JSON : HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/7/3/parsing-json-data-and-swiftyjson)

[Realm swift learning its documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/)

There are many tutorials around the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) all you have to do is need to ask at the search box.

Comment: wow! looks perfect thanks so much! Didn't really know what to google.